# Dynamically adding rows in html form in Google API Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-workspace

[Here](http://www.googleappsscript.org/miscellaneous/creating-form-elements-dynamically-using-google-apps-script-gas) I found excellent tutorial for Dynamically adding rows in Google API Scripts.

However the UI method is deprecated in Google API Scripts. Is similar example possible (dynamic html form?) with new html services introduced by Google API Scripts (in G Suite)?

Comment: You can use the [HTMLService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) to serve HTML and use javascript like normal (mostly) on them.

Answer (score 0):

The API Reference for the UI Service states that it is deprecated and points to the HTML Service: 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/

The API Reference for the HTML Service is here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/

In full disclosure, I have not used the HTML Service, but there are guides and the API Reference (linked above) should help you "convert" the appropriate code. Good luck!!